# VHDL: What will happen in case of "U" or "X" or "Z" signal?

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to design a generic decoder with an input of N-bits:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;    -- standard unresolved logic UX01ZWLH-
use ieee.numeric_std.all;       -- for the signed, unsigned types and arithmetic operations

entity decoder is

    generic (
        input_width : positive := 2
    );

    port (
        input : in std_logic_vector(input_width - 1 downto 0);
        output : out std_logic_vector(2**input_width - 1 downto 0)
    );

end entity decoder;


architecture behavioral of decoder is
begin

    output <= (to_integer(unsigned(input)) => '1', others => '0');

end architecture behavioral;
```

I am wondering what will happen if some bits in the input are "U" or "X" or "Z" for example: what will unsigned(input) return?

Is it possible to set my output to 0 when this case occurs?

More importantly, how are "U", "X", "Z", etc handled in synthesis?
What will happen if we synthetize this decoder and supply him for example with a "Z" input (leaving the input in open circuit)?

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like you should be able to experiment on your own. Have you tried replacing your inputs with these values? What did you see?

Comment: @KingDuken Yes I should have simulated first. It seems that "U", "X", etc are replaced with '0' by the unsigned function.

However I do not have a synthesis tool nor a FPGA, I cannot try and see how it would be synthesized?

By the way, what is the difference between unsigned(input) and TO_UNSIGNED(input)?

Comment: Search on "open source synthesis", or look on the Xilinx or Intel sites for free synthesis tools.

Comment: By the way, unrelated to your actual question, I don't think any synthesizer will successfully synthesize your line `output <= (to_integer(unsigned(input)) => '1', others => '0');`. My general rule of thumb is "if I can imagine the logic to implement this piece of code, then the synthesizer probably can too". Here I cannot envision the logic do to what you're asking, which is "if the input is the number `N`, then set bit `N` of the output and set all other bits to zero".

Comment: @Mr.Snrub I thought it was a way to make a generic decoder, and that the compiler/synthesizer would replace this:

`output <= (to_integer(unsigned(input)) => '1', others => '0');`


by a generic case/select.

The goal was to implement a generic decoder that could be instanciate with any number of inputs.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: @Wheatley That's exactly my point. When thinking about what a synthesizer will do, you must think about the *actual digital logic elements* it will generate. Your mental model of "a generic case/select" is still a construct of code. What would the digital logic look like? This is a super-important question to ask whenever synthesizing code -- if you don't have an answer for it, then it's likely the code will not synthesize. Even if it does synthesize, the resource utilization or timing will be completely unknown, and that is not a good thing.

Comment: @Mr.Snrub This would probably just synthesize as 2**input_width lookup tables.  Each table would have input_width bits and 1 outputs bits.  For example input_width = 6 would just be made from 64 six-input lookup tables in parallel.  You can confirm this looking at the synthesized design schematic from your synthesis tool.

Comment: @user4574 Hmm now that I think about it more, I'd say you're right on the money. Still, I vaguely recall trying to so something like this in the past, and the synthesizer refusing to synthesize it. But time and technology have marched forward since then. I no longer have ready access to a synthesizer, and I'm entirely too lazy to set one up ;-), so for the time being I'll be content with your answer and words like "probably".

Comment: @Mr.Snrub My idea is just to make the compiler replace `output <= (to_integer(unsigned(input)) => '1', others => '0');` by `with input select output` and make it fill `"0001" when "01", "0010" when "10", etc...`, avoiding us to do this tedious task ourselves, specially when you have an high input_width and so many cases to write.
If we write this with/select ourselves, it will be synthesized with no problem.
The idea is just to make the compiler to automatize this transformation before doing the synthesis.

Comment: @user4574 Do you think that this synthesis would be "efficient"? I mean, if I write the `with/select' myself along with the 64 different cases (a tedious task), would it lead to a different synthesis (that would perhaps use less logic blocks) or would it be the same implementation?

Comment: @Wheatley I think it would synthesize the same either way.  But you can always check by just trying it and looking at the utilization report and post-synthesis schematic.  Except for simple pass-through type signals, you always need at least one Look-Up-Table (LUT) for every output anyways.

Answer (score 3):

U and X and Z don't exist on the input pins in real hardware.  The input at the IO pin will always read either 0 or 1.

For the case of leaving the input open circuit (Z), the input pin may read the value as either 0 or 1 depending on what the actual voltage level is.  One way to handle that case is to have a pullup or pulldown resistor on the pin so that it goes into a known state.

X usually represents a net driven by multiple drivers.  But in real life a multiply driven net will be at some voltage.  That voltage is measured by the IO pin and is determined to be either 1 or 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

Let's suppose I have an unitialized signal in my code, and I implement this code on a FPGA. Is there a way to know what would be the state of this signal at the power-on?

And is there a way to set this power-on state in code?

Comment: @Wheatley If you don't set a default then the synthesizer can pick whatever is wants.  What it picks is usually available in the synthesis report.  To set the default state in VHDL you would use...  "signal sig_name : some_type := default_value;".  You can also use := to set the default on inputs of internal entities with unconnected inputs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.
Do you know how is synthesized such an initialization? What would the circuit that initializes a signal look like?

Comment: @Wheatley It depends on the exact part you are using.  For SRAM based FPGAs (like Xilinx) the initial values get loaded when the bit-stream is loaded into the chips SRAM configuration memory.

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit to the other answers, which are all correct.

In general it is very helpful to think about the *intended meaning* of all these values. In VHDL std_logic there are [9 distinct logic values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1164) which we can roughly group as follows:

- Four of these values, '1', '0', 'H', and 'L' represent known logic levels with various drive strengths.
- Another four of these values, 'X', 'U', 'W', and 'Z', all represent unknown voltages so the logic value cannot be assumed to be HIGH or LOW; it could be either one. (And in the actual circuit, the voltage will be recognized as being either HIGH or LOW, but we cannot know which one!)
- Lastly, VHDL has the dedicated "don't care" value of '-', which is purely used as a hint to the synthesizer to help optimize the logic.

So, revisiting your questions:

1. Your first question directly translates to "when I have unknown logic signals, what is the equivalent integer value?" In simulation, we cannot know, so the correct response from the simulator is to output a warning or an error message (hopefully your simulator is doing that), and then if simulation continues, just assign some arbitrary default integer value like zero or MAX_INT.
2. Your second question translates to "can I set the output to 0 when the input is unknown?" Again, in the actual physical circuit there is no such thing as an "unknown" value -- a digital input always sees a zero or a one. In simulation, an "unknown" value is a useful assistance to make sense of what's going on and catch flaws in the design.
3. The others have already ably answered this question, and I've repeated it somewhat here: by definition the physical input cannot see 'U' or 'X', just '0' and '1'.

By the way: one useful little aid to make the simulation act more like the hardware is to use helper functions like [to_x01](https://www.hdlworks.com/hdl_corner/vhdl_ref/VHDLContents/StdLogic1164.htm) in your simulations, to make the values seen in simulation more closely resemble the values that will be seen in the hardware.

Comment: Thank you, it is more clear in my mind now. However I would like to discuss the first point:

1. OK I understand the behavior or the simulator. However, how the "just assign some arbitrary default value" would be translated during the synthesis?

2. Clear, thank you.

3. Clear, thank you.

Comment: Well, as I said, only the simulator can react to "unknown" values because there is no such thing as "unknown" in the real circuit; everything will resolve either to a 0 or a 1. So, it's only the simulator that has to handle the case of "what to do when an 'unknown' value is seen". The synthesized code would be some type of decoder, but per my comment on your original code I don't know that "decoder to an arbitrary number of bits" is something that would actually synthesize. Maybe.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The "HD" in "VHDL" stands for *hardware description*.  "X", "U", etc., are approximations for the simulator.

In reality, the pins will get voltages.  Those voltages will, hopefully, be resolved into 0 or 1 internally to the chip, but if they aren't definitely at the correct value at the correct time, then you can expect all of the usual digital-circuit misbehavior that happens when input voltages are betwixt and between.

Comment: The "X" value can also indicate a "don't care" input value in some situations, so it's not just for simulation.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I believe that would be an incorrect usage of "X", since the VHDL std_logic type has the "-" value as its officially-designated "don't-care" value.

Comment: D'oh! I was confused with Verilog. My apologies @Mr.Snrub and to Tim Wescott.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson don't apologize to me!  The one time I did VHDL for money, the client's engineers came back and said "you're a software engineer, aren't you?".  Which, since I had started by lobbying the customer to put a processor in there to solve that problem, I found mostly amusing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

What is the correct way to initialize a signal so it has the correct value at the power-on of a FPGA?